# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) when trying to index posts in reverse order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display all of my app's "thoughts" in reverse order, but the .all method is saying I can't pass it any arguments? I have seen many examples of this being done, so I am confused as to why I can't get it to work?  Thanks.  Here is my index action:

```
def index
    @thoughts =  Thought.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @thoughts =  Thought.order('created_at desc')
```

Comment: Sorry I thought I accepted the answer.  How do I make it display the post title and content and not just this for a thought..#<Thought::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000048386b0> ??